# Django - How do I pass the 'partial' kwarg from a Serializer to its child serializer

Tags: python, django, orm

When I submit a PATCH request, its sets a partial=True kwarg on the Viewset's serializer, in this case Book, however when Book has an embedded serializer (Chapter), it does not set partial=True on the Chapter nested serializer.

Original code is this:

```py
BookSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  chapters = ChapterSerializer(many=True, read_only=False, required=False)
```

I've tried something like this to pass `partial` down but its not working:

```py
BookSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  chapters = SerializerMethodField()
  def get_chapters(self,obj):
    return ChapterSerializer(many=True, read_only=False, required=False, partial=self.partial)
```

The json request would be something like this:

```json
{
  "id" : 1,
  "title" : "New Book Title",
  "chapters" : [
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "title" : New Chapter 1 Title
    },
    {
      "id" : 7,
      "title" : New Chapter 7 Title
    },
  ]
}
```

So during the request, those two Chapters need to have a partial_update, and take that into account when getting validated.

Comment: It looks like a bad idea to do that. Often this is done with a (possibly) bulk PATCH request to the endpoint for the chapters, not as a subpart when you create/update a book itself.

Comment: What would be the normal behavior if someone sends this type of request? Bad request error?